iOS Safari requires two clicks for a Link with prefetch to work
On Next 14.2, I have a bunch of code that uses StackedList with HeadlessUI. Links contained within these have a Prefetch set to true, which works fine on Safari Mac, Laptop browsers, but on iOS Safari, the behaviour is unexplainable. If it helps, I am attaching a snippet of code from StackList.
<div className="flex min-w-0 gap-x-4 items-center">
        {drag}
        <div className="min-w-0 flex-auto">
          <p className="text-md font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
            <Link prefetch={true} scroll={false} href={href} className="hover:underline truncate line-clamp-1">
              <span className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                {segments.includes(item.slug) && <span className="flex w-3 h-3 me-3 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full"></span>}
                {item.name}
              </span>
            </Link>
          </p>
          <p className="mt-1 flex text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500 truncate line-clamp-1">
            {item.description}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

I am not sure how to go about solving this problem, but I have tried disabling Prefetch, which solves the problem, but it does not give me a great User Experience. Notice that not all Links with  Prefetch on are problematic, like when I am on a specific route /space , then those Prefetch links won't work. But when I am on a different route, then even those Nav Links with Prefetch work correctly.

I spent a day figuring this out, by toggling dozens of component combinations to finally get it.
This is wrong
<li key={`${page.name}-${Math.random(5}`} className="flex">

This is right
<li key={`${page.name}-${useId}`} className="flex">

The wrong approach prevented prefetch from working on iOS Safari. Required double clicks to open the link and single clicks wouldn't open the links. Super weird I know.
While the issue was in the  component, it affected surrounding parent and children components that used . Just putting it out here in case you have a similar issue in the future.
{pages.map((page) => (
          <li key={`${page.name}-${useId}`} className="flex">
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <svg
                className="h-full w-6 flex-shrink-0 text-gray-200"
                viewBox="0 0 24 44"
                preserveAspectRatio="none"
                fill="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path d="M.293 0l22 22-22 22h1.414l22-22-22-22H.293z" />
              </svg>
              <Link prefetch={true} scroll={false} href={page.href} className="truncate line-clamp-1 ml-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700" aria-current={page.current ? 'page' : undefined}>
                {page.name}
              </Link>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}

